# while calling more than one async requests with OkHttp, sometimes callbacks are interfered

Tags: android, okhttp

I have two methods on CustomerService class, and when I call them on HomeFragment, one of the five times, I see that in getTransactions callback I get getCard service response

```
public class CustomerService {

    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();

    .....

    public void getTransactions(String memberId, Callback callback)
    {
        List<Pair> params = new ArrayList<>();
        params.add(new Pair<>("member_id", memberId));

        String url = BASE_URL + "customer/gettransaction/?" + getQuery(params);
        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();
        okHttpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(callback);
    }

    public void getCard(String memberId, Callback callback)
    {
        List<Pair> params = new ArrayList<>();
        params.add(new Pair<>("member_id", memberId));

        String url = BASE_URL + "customer/getcard/?" + getQuery(params);
        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();

        okHttpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(callback);
    }

}
```

And in the fragment class I call them as below:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_activities, container, false);
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

    getCardData();
    getTransactions();

    ....

    return rootView;
}

private void getTransactions() {
    final User currentUser = UserRepository.getUser(realm);

    customerService.getTransactions(currentUser.getMember_id(), new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, final IOException e) {

            Log.d(TAG, "Transaction service error: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {

            Type responseType = new TypeToken<WsResponse<List<WsTransaction>>>() {}.getType();
            final List<WsTransaction> wsTransactionList = LoyaltyService.getWsResponseData(response, responseType);

            if (wsTransactionList != null) {

               ....
            }
        }
    });
}

private void getCardData() {
    final User currentUser = UserRepository.getUser(realm);

    customerService.getCard(currentUser.getMember_id(), new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, final IOException e) {

            Log.d(TAG, "Customer - GetCard service error: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {

            Type responseType = new TypeToken<WsResponse<WsCard>>() {}.getType();
            final WsCard wsCard = LoyaltyService.getWsResponseData(response, responseType);
            if (wsCard != null) {

                .....
            }
        }
    });
}
```

If I delay calling getTransactions for half second, then it has no problem. Or when I debug, I don't have any problem. Can somebody help me to understand what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a server side problem.

Answer (score 0):

The enqueue with a callback is asynchronous, so most likely you are using the same callback but not waiting for the login to succeed. If this is the case and you are expecting a certain order of results, then it's quite possible the second getCard request completes sometimes before the login.

More context would be needed to confirm if this is possibly the case.

Comment: I'm not using the same callback, I added more context

Comment: the login call and callback isn't present.

Comment: sorry, I renamed them